# JPA Hibernate using @joincolumn for @ManyToOne

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying to solve this for a long time. I have an entity called **status** and an entity called **info**. The info entity has id, name and the status entity has fields id, user.

I want the server to return the info dto with an additional field - a "**price**" field. To make this joincolumn, I need to use a query like : select price from status s join info i on s.id=i.statusid;

Note that I made the statusid column using @joincolumn like this and it works but Im not sure how to add another joincolumn:

```
@Entity
private Long statusid;
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="statusid")
private Status status;
```

How can I now get the price field from within the info entity, joining it with the status entity? It is a @manytoone mapping.

Comment: can you provide complete entity code for Status and Info

Comment: you can try to write native query, but first you should provide complete explanation of your problem.